# Is there a filter/search option available for navigating the 'Find Content > Files' page?

Tags: nodes, search, files

I have a site with thousands of files uploaded, and Drupal's admin view doesn't seem to offer a comprehensive filter for the Files view like it does with the Content view.

There also apparently isn't the option to search the files either.

**Files view:**

[image]

Is any such filter or search option available? This would make updating files 10 x faster!

Comment: Define "better", please.

Comment: By 'better', I mean something with more options than 'status' and 'type'. Something like the Content view filter, but with 'filename', 'author', 'date created', 'date modified' etc, and preferably a search function

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is create a custom [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) view to suit your needs!
It can have all the filters and sortable columns you want, and ... checkboxes so you can perform actions on the selected items.

See a guide here for using [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu8KkdjPucM).

Don't forget to set the views access permssions as you want to create an admin only vbo view !